# Changing directions path color in HERE MAPS in Javascript

Tags: colors, routes, maps, here-api

Using HereMaps Javascript API, how do i change direction colors for different waypoints.

Comment: Please tell us more about the api and code you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the LineString in a new `H.map.Polyline`? If so, `H.map.Polyline.Options` has a style property. It should end up looking like:

```
polyline = new H.map.Polyline(lineString, {
    style: {
      lineWidth: 2,
      strokeColor: 'hex | rgb | rgba',
    }
});
```